# Bloggger template hell

Tags: templates, blogger

I've gotten from the Blogger Help Forum the link to this site and I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask about it but consider leaving my head on shoulders. :)

I was wondering, since I bought this one template online with lifetime support for my blog ( https://helenarakic.blogspot.ba/
 ), I've tried 3 times to reach out to them to fix me something on the site but they've always asked me to add them as admins and that's it, they've never done anything.

Perhaps someone knows who could help me with the code?

It's basic things I'd like to change, like to show 10 posts on the page instead of 6, event thought I set it on the Layout (main) to show 10, the template doesn't render it correctly.., and that when someone clicks on the image that it would open the article and not the image.

I've been doing joomla templates but it's been like 10 years ago and now when I see a custom made code I've actually no idea what I'm looking at. :)

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to share your template code!

Comment: The code is too long for here to post so here it is :)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mPiQrGL74kffBzhSnHaQj0tziTIGUya7

Comment: Btw. Is anyone familiar with AdSense and if the custom template can affect showing adds?

I added the code from MyAdds to the template HTML, same code to the HTML/Java and AdSense gadget, set it to show adds inbetween posts, it only shows the add in the header.

In Adsense I set all the add types to be shown everywhere, just as in the Earnings on blogger.

Does anyone have a guess what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

search and change `max-results=6` with value `10` and/if need, also change value `var pageCount=9;`

Comment: Would make sense that this is the issue and i changed it, but nothing happened, I even tried removing the script code in which both are embedded and..nothing. I really don't know what else to try..it's literally making me crazy. Does anyone have bloggger? I can make them admin if they're willing to try. I would more than appreciate any effort.

Comment: not working?
if you trust me, let me help to solve your problem.

Comment: It is better for me to trust you than to loose my nerves and continue tinkering until I ruin it. :)

What email should I invite you as?

Comment: I just read your message, seems at last I'm alone with my troubles. But a big thank you either way @mylastof! :) 

Is there a site where i can hire someone to look into it? (some freelancers)